Is there a way to execute export in exasol via websockets?
I'm trying to execute this query in EXASOL:
EXPORT table1 INTO LOCAL CSV FILE '/tmp/my_table.csv' COLUMN SEPARATOR = ';';

This is working fine through jdbc (dbeaver), and the csv is created.
But if I execute it through websockets (using js @exasol/exasol-driver-ts library, execute method) I get this error:
 Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'numResults')

It is on premise Exasol 8.
Is there a way to make it work?

EXPORT INTO LOCAL CSV FILE syntax is only supported using Exaplus or JDBC, not Websockets according to the documentation. You can try to create an FTP server use cloud storage like S3 and then do a generic EXPORT INTO CSV command instead.

The link is not available. I searched for id, but I did'n find.

Sorry, fixed the URL. There is a note about local files within the table.
